# How to get books listed in someone's Facebook profile in Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph-api-explorer

I've been reading FBSDK docs and found the Graph API Explorer, which I think would be a great way to test before I implement this feature in my iOS code. So I go here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/books/

and click on Graph API Explorer. Once in the Explorer page, I click on GetToken...Get User Access Token, and just to be sure I select ALL permissions.

In the url:

```
{user-id}/books
```

I replace {user-id} with the actual 15-digit long ID of my account and I click Submit.

I see this as a result:

```
{
  "data": [
  ]
}
```

What's going on? Why can't I see my books? According to the documentation I should see "books listed in my Facebook profile". And I do have 2 books listed in my profile.

BTW - I went to my profile and made sure I share the books with Public, so now it says: "Share books you like on Facebook with:  Public", but it didn't help - still get an empty array when requesting .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you get the same for `/me/books`?

Comment: Yes, same thing - empty data array. There was actually an answer here a moment ago that someone deleted. The answer suggested to try url **me/books.reads** which produces the desired results. I can see my 2 books. BTW the books don't have to be Public in my profile. Just changed it to Friends permission and it's sill shows.

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer earlier today but then it got deleted. The correct path that provides the books from user profile is:

```
me/books.reads
```

with permission

```
user_actions.books
```